# texture matching between patches of an image

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, opencv, local-features

I have an image `A` which I have divided into `4 x 4` subband images. For a given patch `P1` in image `A`, I need to find another patch `P2`  in the same image `A` which is `most similar: have same texture.`

Till now my appraoch is to create feature vectors `Fi` for all `i` patches and using Euclid's distance formula find out which patch's feature vector is closest to given patch P1's feature vector.

Currently I have added following features:

> 1. Mean & Standard Deviation of brightness (using L channel of LAB colorspace)
> 2. Mean & Standard Deviation of color values in A channel of LAB colorspace
> 3. Mean & Standard Deviation of color values in B channel of LAB colorspace

Although I am getting similar patches but I still think the matching can be improved if I incorporate more prominent features (which I'm unaware of).

Following are my queries:

> 1. I have a doubt whether this is a good way to compare color between two patches.
> 2. Please suggest some more good features which can be helpful to get a proper differentiation.
> 3. Although most of my images are proper but are there any restrictions/drawbacks with the approach if image is dark and/or noisy? If yes, is there a good alternative approach or
>      feature(s)?

Please help!

Comment: Interesting question!  Can you perhaps add an example of what the "unexpected" match is? What match *are* you getting?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upload any images due to some restrictions where I am working. But, the problem is the closest patch which I am getting is not correct. Even for 'red' colored textured patch, the patch getting matched is one which contains light background colors.

Comment: @stalin you can always find a similar or simulated image which is closer to your original image. If you don't have one then create one & post it! It will be useful!

Comment: How big are your feature vectors? Have you tried normalising them?

Comment: Currently, I have only 3 features in each of the feature vector: std of brightness, std of color values in A channel and std of color values in B channel

Comment: I'm sorry, but there was an implementation mistake from my side that's why I was getting bad matches. Now the matching is proper. However, I would still like to improve patch matching and I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean and standard deviation are two measurements of a distribution. Others you could also use are higher order moments like 'skewness' (how skewed the distribution is) and 'kurtosis' (how 'peaky' the distribution is).

However, what I would try is a *histogram* of the values for each of the channels. For example, if you used a histogram with 16 bins, you would get a feature vector with 48 values. The histogram bin values can be thought of as a descriptor of the distribution.

To account for changes in brightness, you need to introduce some illumination invariance. Already the LAB colour-space splits the image into luminance (L) and color (AB) channels. To achieve illumination invariance I would normalise the L channel histogram values using the norm of whatever measure you are using (in this case, euclidean distance, it would be the l2 norm). Normalising the A or B channels is probably not necessary. The normalisation accounts for any linear changes in luminance.

Depending on the images, you could also add vectors like:

- histogram of oriented gradients (HOG)
- histogram of connected components (make B/W then count how many pixels are white in the 8 connected neighbours)
- k-means clustering of LAB values to get k centre LAB values which you can compare to other images.

and so on.

Comment: So, in my feature vector Fi for each patch i, I should have histogram for each color channel? And while comparing two patches, I must calculate distance between respective histograms using some distance like Chi-square?

Comment: Yes, but you could just use euclidean distance

Comment: OK! Further, I am unaware of the term 'illumination invariance' and thus don't understand this 'normalise the L channel histogram values using the norm'. Can you please add something about it or give me a link which explains it? I also found the same normalizing thing while studying about HoG. Thanks!

Comment: Imagine you have a vector $\mathbf{a}$ and another vector that is a scaled version of $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b} = \lambda\mathbf{a}$. If you compared the two vectors with euclidian distance you would get some non-zero result. But what if you wanted to compare the two vectors without regard to their magnitude? To do this you would normalise them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)  The type of norm you use depends on the distance measure you are using. e.g. you dont normalise with the l1 norm (manhattan distance) if using an l2 distance measure (euclidean distance)

Comment: Illumination is typically a linear increase in brightness. e.g. for an image $a(x,y)$, a brighter image might be $b(x,y) = \lambda a(x,y)$. So if you wanted to introduce illumination invariance for some measurement $\mathcal{O}$, then you must have $\mathcal{O}(a) = \mathcal{O}(b)$.

Comment: To my recent implementation, I have added histogram features. For each patch I caculate 3 histograms (L, A, B), normalize L histogram using L2 norm and then add all bin values of three histograms to feature vector. Then, compute distances between feature vectors using Euclidean distance. Is this right approach? I am getting relatively bad matches than before.

Comment: Will it make difference if I put 3 histograms (intact) in feature vector and later while comparing patches, compute distances between each histograms seperately. But then I'll have 3 different numbers! How can I combine them and report a single similarity measure?

Comment: You might just have to experiment with different things. For example, weight the histograms differently etc. Maybe use more bins / less bins / different features / different distance measurements, etc. If you have classes of features you could use k-nearest neighbour. You could do some statistical analysis to see if your features are good. If you have a set of known good matches you could use machine learning to train a classifier. There are so many options :)

Comment: With you images, just looking at the patches what features does your brain identify as being important to differentiate them? (The human brain is the worlds best image analysis system)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `LAB`, it is a good way if you are interested in the differences as humans perceive them.

About texture, I would suggest taking a look at some proprietary texture descriptors:

1. Gray level co-occurrence matrix.
2. Response to wavelets